# Server goes into infinite loop and gives exception of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

Running my java project locally gives GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS exception.

The exception is:

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storage' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/storage/GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.storage.Storage]: Factory method 'storage' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
>
> See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

I followed the link: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials and performed all the mentioned steps.
Also updated the local key file with the new `key.json`

The snapshot of the exception is:
[image: Error Snap]

Comment: The issue is related to the Storage client not being able to find your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I guess that you did the `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"`, maybe the path is not correct. If that doesn't work you can also pass the credentials in your [code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_the_path_to_the_service_account_key_in_code). A sample of the code you're executing would be good to be able to help you further. Also a sample of the export command you've used.

Comment: Are you in windows?

Comment: @JRichardsz No I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: @bhito export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/swathi/secrets/key.json"

Comment: Have you tried setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` on your code? (i have provided you the link in the comment above). Also some sample of code you are using would be good to help you further.

Comment: @bhito Yes it is resolved now. Apparently my export path was not correct as pointed out by you. Thanks. :)

Comment: No problem! Good to know that you managed to solve the issue! :)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @bhito, export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]" with correct path resolved the issue.

For more information, follow the link:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_the_path_to_the_service_account_key_in_code